# changing the sizen and appareance of the broadcast section in netlogo

Tags: netlogo, hubnet

Hi I am trying to make a chat for a social experiment in NetLogo, right now I made    the basic chat, but now I wonder if there is a way to change the height of the   broadcast area, because I want that the chat area is big enough so I could put a   lot of messages there without the need of using the scroll bar. Thank you.

Comment: not sure what you mean by "broadcast section" or "broadcast area". it might help if you included a screen shot that illustrates what you mean.

Comment: I'm almost certain kaint means the part of a HubNet window that broadcasts go to. And no, unfortunately there is no way to resize them.

Comment: yeah i meaned that part, and ok thanks, if you wiuld need to create a chat using hubnet, how would you do it then>?